# Restoring the entire ampps folder in wordpress installation directory

Tags: database, wordpress, backup, restore, ampps

I have been working in a wordpress project locally with ampps. Unfortunately, my system crashed. But I made a copy of the entire ampps directory and kept it safe. My question is, can I restore this backed directory to a new ampps installation (replacing the ampps directory) so that I can restore the project.

Looking forward to your suggestions

Thanks